# How to keep background aspect ratio on different screens

Tags: android

I prepared a background image for my application in Galaxy S9+ screen ratio (almost 2:1), such that it will be big enough for all screen sizes. Then I defined the background drawable in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:tileMode="disabled">
</bitmap>
```

Then I use it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.GameActivity">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="..." />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/g_viewPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/activity_background">

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

When I run application on devices with ratio similar to SGS9+, background seems to be correct. However, when I run the app on, say Galaxy S6 with screen ratio 16:9, background is vertically compressed (even though bottom and top parts are cut off - as designed).

How can I set up the background to be stretched horizontally and cut off vertically, but so that aspect ratio will be kept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="clip_vertical|fill_horizontal"
android:tileMode="disabled">
</bitmap>
```

If this won't work, try tweaking Layout Gravity to clip vertically